# Cell's .Interior.ColorIndex Value Different From What Is Visible

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

SO Community,

The problem is that I have a cell that is colored red via conditional formatting, but when I check the cell's `.Interior.ColorIndex`, it returns `35`, which corresponds to light green.

### Contextual Information

1. The cell in question is a *merged cell*, named `partNumber_1`, and it spans cells I12:L12
2. In the immediate window, `?Range("I12").Interior.ColorIndex` returns `35`
3. `?Range("partNumber_1").Interior.ColorIndex` returns `35`
4. If I change 2. and 3. to `.Interior.Color` (to get the long value), it returns `13434828` which corresponds to `RGB(205, 255, 205)`
5. The named range in question, `partNumber_1` belongs to another named range, `ScannedPartNumbers`, which is the named range referenced in the conditional formatting formula.
6. `?Range("ScannedPartNumbers").Interior.ColorIndex` also returns `35`

I apply and remove the conditional formatting via VBA, where `target` is the `ScannedPartNumbers` range, `fillColor` is 3 (red), and `fontColor` is 6 (yellow).

```
Public Sub AddBlankCellFormatCondition(target As range, fillColor As Integer, Optional fontColor As Integer = 1)
    target.Parent.Unprotect password:=Strings.Mypw
    With target
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlBlanksCondition
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = fillColor
            .Font.ColorIndex = fontColor
        End With
    End With
    target.Parent.Protect password:=Strings.Mypw, userinterfaceonly:=True
End Sub
```

All of the cells in the `ScannedPartNumbers` named range have turned red, but I haven't yet been able to find a single cell that has the `.Interior.ColorIndex` or `.Interior.Color` value that even remotely resembles red!

Help please?

Comment: `Range.Interior.ColorIndex` and conditional format colour are unrelated. `Range.Interior.ColorIndex` is the colour that will be applied if no CF's are triggered

Comment: @chrisneilsen Do you know how to see prove from an automated test standpoint that the cell is actually red? Is there a current conditional format color property or something I can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of Conditional Formatting as a sheet of transparency that's laid over the top of your cell formats. Conditional formatting doesn't actually change the interior colour of the cell, it places a new colour over the top of it and forces Excel to print that colour instead.

The result is that the cells `Color` and `ColorIndex` values do not change, so VBA checking them will not see any difference.

Rather than looking at the colour of the cells, may I suggest using the same conditional logic you're using for Conditional Formatting to check which cells you want to work with?

Colour options in Excel are strictly there for display purposes, and generally should not be seen as values. You can't sort or filter by colour, for good reason. While it is perforce possible to do something of the sort with VBA, it's rarely a good idea, and generally better to encourage users to use values to sort and filter by, rather than using colours.

Comment: This new truth makes me now need to ask another question. Is there a way you know of to see what a cell's currently displayed color is? I am writing automated tests using c# and I'm trying to test that the color red is actually applied.